# Comparing lists by iterating over the elements character by character

Tags: python, list

I have two lists with names and I want to compare the first name to all the names of the other list and see how many letters are similar but I am having trouble in doing so. Here is my code thus far:

```
listss = ['SAM SMITH', 'JAKE BLAK', 'CONNOR ELLY']
lists2 = ['BEN SMITH']

matching = []

for name in lists2:
   for ch in name:
       for names in listss:
           for chs in names:
               if chs == ch:
               matching.append(ch)
print(matching)
```

I want to compare 'BEN SMITH' to every name in listss to see how many letters are equal to each other. So an example would be comparing 'BEN SMITH' to 'SAM SMITH', the result would be 5 letters in common which are 'SMITH' the first three letters aren't equal. Is there a way to do that? I have been trying to do it with a for loop but no luck yet.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `zip()` function...but give an example of your two lists please?

Comment: and what is the question? problem?

Comment: So listss = ['SAM SMITH', 'JAKE BLAK', 'CONNOR ELLY']    and lists2 = ['BEN SMITH'], I just want to know if there is a way to take BEN SMITH and see how many letters it has in common with each name in listss.

Comment: What's the desired result for your example? And please put the whole example in the question.

Comment: I want to take 'BEN SMITH' and compare each character to 'SAM SMITH'. The result would be 5 letters in common, which are "SMITH". The first three letters aren't equal.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: What should be the result for 'JOHN SMITH'? 5 or 0? if 0, the answer is easy with `zip`

Comment: The result for 'JOHN SMITH' should be 5 because first names don't match up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop

```
lists1 = ['SAM SMITH', 'JAKE BLAK', 'CONNOR ELLY']
lists2 = ['BEN SMITH']

for name2 in lists2:
    for name1 in lists1:
       matching = []
       for ch2 in name2:
           for ch1 in name1:
               if ch1 == ch2 and ch1 != ' ' and ch1 not in matching:
                   matching.append(ch1)
       print(len(matching), matching)

# 5 ['S', 'M', 'I', 'T', 'H']
# 2 ['B', 'E']
# 2 ['E', 'N']
```

Or you can use `set()`

```
lists1 = ['SAM SMITH', 'JAKE BLAK', 'CONNOR ELLY']
lists2 = ['BEN SMITH']

for name2 in lists2:
    for name1 in lists1:
        matching = (set(name1) & set(name2)) - set(' ')
        print(len(matching), matching)

# 5 {'T', 'I', 'S', 'M', 'H'}
# 2 {'B', 'E'}
# 2 {'N', 'E'}
```